# Function caller code VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

## Problem

When you want to look directly at the arguments of your UDF (not their *values*, which can be passed directly, but the *formula that gave these values*), you can use Application.Caller.Formula and parse out the arguments to find out.

Is there any way to see the line of VBA code which called a Function, so that you can parse out its arguments in a similar way?

## Background

A while ago I created a UDF which was essentially another approach to array functions*. What I wanted to do was take some statement which evaluates to `True`/`False`

```
LEN(A1)>LEN(B1)
```

And evaluate it over an array. So say the above function was placed in cell `A1`, then to evaluate over the array `A1:A100` would be the same as creating the array

```
{LEN(A1)>LEN(B1),LEN(A2)>LEN(B2),[...]} 'you may recognise this as an array formula ={LEN(A1:A100)>LEN(B1:B100)}
```

**For context, this was before I knew about array formulae*

I was frustrated with the syntax of certain array-handling Excel functions, like `COUNTIF`, which takes the arguments in the following form

```
COUNTIF(range_To_Evalueate_Over, "string_Representing_Boolean_Test")
```

The string argument presents the following limitations

- Not any boolean returning statement can be used as a test; there is no way of looking at properties of the range which you evaluate over other than their values

  - So you can't use functions like LEN() to get more data about the range
  - You can not reference other cells relative to the range (Like `B1` relative to `A1`)
- The string is static at runtime, you cannot step-into the function to see what the string will evaluate to for a given cell from the range you are evaluating

I much prefer the versatility of the conditional formatting formulae. They take the form of array formulae, where any offsets (`B1` relative to `A1`) are calculated relative to the TL cell of the range that the conditional formatting is applied to.

That prompted me to create a UDF which has a structure like this

```
evaluateOverRange(range_to_evalute_over As Range, boolean_test_on_TL_Cell As Boolean) As Boolean() 'returns an array equal in size to the evaluate range
```

Used like

```
evaluateOverRange(A1:A100,LEN(A1)<LEN(B1))
```

Note

- Boolean test is not a string, so can be evaluated step by step in Excel
- Boolean test is guaranteed to be Boolean thanks to type declaration
- Boolean test is relative to the first cell (`A1`) in the evaluate range (`A1:A100`)

  - I.e. `B1` is replaced with `A1.Offset(0,1)`
- Since `boolean_test_on_TL_Cell` is not a string, it tells us nothing about the actual test, it just passes the result of the test on the `A1`, it is actually useless within the UDF so is ignored

  - To obtain the test string `"LEN(A1)<LEN(B1)"`, the `Application.Caller.Formula` is read, and the relevant argument of `evaluateOverRange` is parsed out

In order to evaluate some worksheet function over an array in VBA, you can use the `Evaluate` method

```
Dim colA As Range: Set colA = [A1:A100] 'range_to_evaluate_over in my udf
Dim cellA As Range
Dim cellB as Range
Dim outputArray(1 To 100) As Boolean

For i = 1 To 100
    Set cellA = colA(i)
    Set cellB = cellA.Offset(0,1) 'all cells that arent the TL cell in colA (i.e., not A1) are set relative to the top left cell
    outputArray(i) = Evaluate("LEN(" & cellA.Value & ")>LEN(" & cellB.Value ")")
Next i
```

---

Right, so all that was for worksheet functions, and somewhat pointless given array functions do the same thing. But now I want to use the same approach within VBA.

Specifically, I want to filter an array of custom classes based on some function of their properties, using actual VBA Boolean returning code rather than a string.

```
Sub FilterMyClassArray() 'Prints how many items in arrayToFilter whose properties match certain conditions
    Dim arrayToFilter(1 To 100) As New myClass
    Dim filteredArray() As myClass 
    Dim tlClass As myClass 'pretend class used only for intellisense and to create 
boolean test
    Set filteredArray = filterClassArray(arrayToFilter, tlClass.PropertyA > 3 And 
   tlClass.PropertyB = "hat")
   Debug.Print "Number left after filtering:" ; Ubound(filteredArray)
End Sub

Function filterClassArray(ByVal inutArray() As myClass, classTest As Boolean) As myClass 'returns an output array which is equal to the input array filtered by some test
'Somehow get what classTest actually was
'Evaluate classTest over each item in inputArray
'If boolean test evaluates to true, add to output array, otherwise skip
End Function
```

I imagine some manipulation of the code modules will be required (both to get the string of code which represents the test, and to actually evaluate it), but I want to check feasibility before I dig too deep.

Comment: Your task would be much more (ok, a little more) straightforward if you would pass the test as a string and not as a boolean expression: doing it the way you show is just a long way around to arrive at the same point, as you're anticipating somehow parsing the calling code to extract the text underlying the test.  Why make that round-trip when you could just pass the test as a string in the first place?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for reading this! The round trip is for the same reason I didn't want to pass the info as a string for my worksheet function. Namely: I can use intellisense and step into the function if I use a *live* expression rather than a string. To a lesser extent it also guarantees the validity of the test with the type declaration. The idea is that if I get the majority of the leg-work done now, it will save me time and be more useful in the future.

Comment: Workarounds for the first would be first to type out the code, then convert to a string. For the latter I could just use the immediate window. But I think you can see the potential benefits of not having to do that

Comment: It looks like more work to me - if you're not doing this dynamically (building your filters at runtime based on user input) then I'm not seeing much of a benefit given the hoops you'll need to jump through to make it work.

Comment: I really don't think this is possible. For one thing, VBA doesn't support reflection so you'll have to convert property names to strings yourself; for another, you're going to need to use the `CallByName()` function to obtain the values and then `Evaluate()` to acquire the results, and even then `Evaluate` uses the Excel formula syntax, so for example you'd need to convert the`... And ...` syntax to `AND(..., ...)` And instancing a new class object purely to obtain properties by intellisense seems odd. I'd say this needs a re-think.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a think about this and a solution might be possible if you'd be prepared to use something approximating a `Linq` syntax.

If I understand the requirements correctly, you need to:

1. obtain a string value for each property name,
2. record the evaluation and ultimately run it as a string,
3. have intellisense access to the properties, and
4. have the ability to debug the evaluation on each iteration.

Regarding #1 and #3, the only way of doing this in VBA would be to code the values manually. If you code them in your class then the class can become cumbersome and some might say it compromises the single responsibility principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you code them in a separate 'container' (eg class, type, collection, etc.), then there's a risk of some being missed or of corruption if you change the property names. An Interface class might mitigate these issues.

For #2, I can't see any way around it: the evaluation must be entered as a string. An enum (and associated intellisense) might alleviate things a bit though.

Item #4 is purely a coding architecture issue.

**First the syntax**

I'm sure there are VBA solutions on the internet which implement a pretty decent mock-up of `Linq`, but further down is a skeleton version to give you the idea. The end result is that your query syntax could look like this:

```
Dim query As cLinq
Dim p As INameable
Dim arrayToFilter(1 To 100) As INameable
Dim filteredArray() As INameable

Set query = New cLinq
With query
    .SELECT_USING_INTERFACE p
    .FROM arrayToFilter
    .WHERE p.PropertyA, EQUAL_TO, 3
    .AND_WHERE p.PropertyB, EQUAL_TO, "hat"
    filteredArray = .EXECUTE
End With
```

**The interface**

As far as VBA is concerned an interface is really just a class module with a list of properties and methods that you want a class to implement. In your case, I've created a class and called it *INameable*, with the following sample code to match your example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get PropertyA() As Long
End Property
Public Property Let PropertyA(RHS As Long)
End Property
Public Property Get PropertyB() As String
End Property
Public Property Let PropertyB(RHS As String)
End Property
```

Your `MyClass` class then implements this interface. For the sake of consistency, I've called the class *cMyClass*:

```
Option Explicit
Implements INameable

Private mA As Long
Private mB As String

Private Property Let INameable_PropertyA(RHS As Long)
    mA = RHS
End Property

Private Property Get INameable_PropertyA() As Long
    INameable_PropertyA = mA
End Property

Private Property Let INameable_PropertyB(RHS As String)
    mB = RHS
End Property

Private Property Get INameable_PropertyB() As String
    INameable_PropertyB = mB
End Property
```

I've created a second class, called cNames, which also implements the interface, and this one produces the string names of the properties. As a quick and dirty method it just stores the name of the last property used:

```
Option Explicit
Implements INameable

Private mName As String

Private Property Let INameable_PropertyA(RHS As Long)
End Property

Private Property Get INameable_PropertyA() As Long
    mName = "PropertyA"
End Property

Private Property Let INameable_PropertyB(RHS As String)
End Property

Private Property Get INameable_PropertyB() As String
    mName = "PropertyB"
End Property

Public Property Get CurrentName() As String
    CurrentName = mName
End Property
```

You wouldn't have to use an interface and some might argue it's not necessary or even correct to do so, but at least it gives you an idea of how it could be implemented if you went this route.

**The Linq class**

The final class is really just a helper class to create the intellisense syntax you need and to process the evaluation. It's by no means thorough, but might get you started if the idea appealed to you. I've called this class *cLinq*:

```
Option Explicit
'Enumerator to help with intellisense.
Public Enum Operator
    EQUAL_TO
    GREATER_THAN
    LESS_THAN
    GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO
    LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO
    NOT_EQUAL_TO
End Enum

Private mP As cNames
Private mQueries As Collection
Private mByAnd As Boolean
Private mFromArray As Variant
Public Sub SELECT_USING_INTERFACE(p As INameable)
    'Insantiate the name of properties class.
    Set mP = New cNames
    Set p = mP
End Sub
Public Sub FROM(val As Variant)
    'Array containing objects to be interrogated.
    mFromArray = val
End Sub
Public Sub WHERE(p As Variant, opr As Operator, val As Variant)
    'First query.
    Set mQueries = New Collection
    AddQuery opr, val
End Sub
Public Sub AND_WHERE(p As Variant, opr As Operator, val As Variant)
    'Subsequent query using AND.
    mByAnd = True
    AddQuery opr, val
End Sub
Public Sub OR_WHERE(p As Variant, opr As Operator, val As Variant)
    'Subsequent query using OR.
    mByAnd = False
    AddQuery opr, val
End Sub
Public Function EXECUTE() As Variant
    Dim o As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim matches As Collection
    Dim output() As Object

    'Iterate the array of objects to be checked.
    Set matches = New Collection
    For i = LBound(mFromArray) To UBound(mFromArray)
        Set o = mFromArray(i)
        result = EvaluatedQueries(o)
        If result Then matches.Add o
    Next

    'Transfer matched objects to an array.
    ReDim output(0 To matches.Count - 1)
    i = LBound(output)
    For Each o In matches
        Set output(i) = o
        i = i + 1
    Next

    EXECUTE = output
End Function
Private Function EvaluatedQueries(o As Object) As Boolean
    Dim pep As Variant, val As Variant
    Dim evalString As String
    Dim result As Boolean

    For Each pep In mQueries
        'Obtain the property value by its string name
        val = CallByName(o, pep(0), VbGet)
        'Build the evaluation string.
        evalString = ValToString(val) & pep(1)
        'Run the evaluation
        result = Evaluate(evalString)
        'Exit the loop if AND or OR conditions are met.
        If mQueries.Count > 1 Then
            If (mByAnd And Not result) Or (Not mByAnd And result) Then Exit For
        End If
    Next

    EvaluatedQueries = result
End Function
Private Sub AddQuery(opr As Operator, val As Variant)
    Dim pep(1) As Variant

    'Create a property/evaluation pair and add to collection,
    'eg pep(0): "PropertyA", pep(1): " = 3"
    pep(0) = mP.CurrentName
    pep(1) = OprToString(opr) & ValToString(val)
    mQueries.Add pep
End Sub
Private Function OprToString(opr As Operator) As String
    'Convert enum values to string operators
    Select Case opr
        Case EQUAL_TO
            OprToString = " = "
        Case GREATER_THAN
            OprToString = " > "
        Case LESS_THAN
            OprToString = " < "
        Case GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO
            OprToString = " >= "
        Case LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO
            OprToString = " <= "
        Case NOT_EQUAL_TO
            OprToString = " <> "
    End Select
End Function
Private Function ValToString(val As Variant) As String
    Dim result As String

    'Add inverted commas if it's a string.
    If VarType(val) = vbString Then
        result = """" & val & """"
    Else
        result = CStr(val)
    End If

    ValToString = result
End Function
```